# Simplest Arraylist implementation in C

Tags: c, arraylist

I think the title says most of my problem.

I am new to C and I am looking for the simplest way to use an arraylist library
in one of my executables.

I have a particular type of struct which I would like to "feed" to the list and then be able to add, remove, iterate and access all of my elements with some ease.

I had a look at this website:

http://www.koders.com/c/fid4E4658B6DA7F7E9C331AC8D267BF5D9D6E5577C3.aspx

from which I copied and compiled my program against but couldn't figure out how to initialize the arraylist.

Therefore I would also really appreciate it if you could also attach a very simple example of how to use it.

Thank you all in advance.

Comment: I would suggest a different language than C from your requirements and your skill.

Comment: There's not much to gain from using an ArrayList (of sorts) in C.  Not just that, but did you look at the .c file and not just the .h file?  You'd need both.

Comment: Suffice it to say that I have to use C. I used both the header and the .c file but "Arraylist arraylist_create(const Boolean (*equals)(const Object object_1, const Object object_2))" doesn't make much sense to me....

Comment: The link is dead, by the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter to `arraylist_create` is a function pointer to a 
comparison function taking 2 `Object`s (generic pointers) as arguments and returning
a `Boolean` indicating whether the arguments are considered equal or not.

This function is needed e.g. for looking for a certain element in the list (`arraylist_contains`).

It goes along this line (error handling missing):

```
#include "arraylist.h"

typedef int the_type;

const Boolean compare_function(const Object a, const Object b) 
{
    return *(the_type*)a == *(the_type*)b;
}

int main(void) 
{
    Arraylist the_list;
    int x = 42, y = 23, z = 3, i;

    the_list = arraylist_create(compare_function);

    arraylist_add(the_list, &x);
    arraylist_add(the_list, &y);
    arraylist_add(the_list, &z);

    for (i = 0; i < arraylist_size(the_list); ++i) {
        /* the printf works just because the_type == int */
        printf("%i: %i\n", i, *(the_type*)arraylist_get(the_list, i));
    }

    arraylist_clear(the_list);
    arraylist_free(the_list);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation and your detailed code. However it won't compile..due to "undefined references" to the methods..Did you test it out?

Comment: Yes, I tested it. "undefined references" is a linker error. Did you link arraylist.o to your program?

Comment: I apologize! my bad! Forgot to include the entire arraylist.c ! Thanks a lot for your time and help!

Comment: hmmm... one last thing before you get rid of me..:) The code seems to work for the typedef of int that you wrote earlier but not for the typedef of a struct that I want to use..! However if I remove the external dereferences all is good... return (struct_type*)a == (struct_type*)b;

Comment: In that case you'll probably need a more sophisticated comparison function. `(struct_type*)a == (struct_type*)b` checks whether both pointers are the same, i.e. pointing to the same `struct` object. If there is another `struct` with the same values it will be considered different. Something like `((type*)a)->field == ((type*)b)->field` with an `&&` for all relevant fields should do.